# Select td which contains a (Anchor)  tag using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML code as given below.
I want to select all td which contains `a`(anchor) as an immediate child (Here First TD tag) using jQuery.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="abc.aspx">ABC</a></td>
    <td>Second Level<span> >> </span>
        <div>
          <table>
             <tr>
               <td><a href="efg.aspx">EFG</a></td>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure that's tabular data you have there. If not use `li`s.

Comment: By the way, you forgot a `</div>` after the inner table (and the `</table>` but I think you noticed it :) )

Comment: @RepWhorinfPeeHaa : I have tried to use nested ul > li but they required specific !doctype for proper display in IE8 and above version.

Comment: @sp00m : thanks for notifying me .. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Description

Many ways to do this

You can use the parent css selector or jQuery's `parent()` function.
Check out the sample and this [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Xrfet/)

#### Sample

1. `​$("td > a").parent()`
2. `$("td > a:parent")`

#### More Information

- [jQuery - :parent Selector](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/)
- [jQuery - parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick:

```
$("td > a").parent();
```

Comment: Thanks sp00m...it was simple than i thought

Answer (score 3):

Remember that jQuery has the `:has()` pseudo-selector.

```
$('td:has(> a)')
```

This will select all `<td>` elements with an immediate `<a>` child.

Answer (score 2):

Select the anchor using css child selector to check that the anchor is a child of a td then call parent

```
$('td > a').parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
$('td').filter(function(){
    if($(this).children('a').length > 0){
        return this;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give an #id to your table, you can do something like this:

```
$(function(){
    myTds = [];
    $('#mytable td>a').each(function(){
        myTds.push($(this).parent())
    })

//do stuff with your tds
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var listOfTD = $("table td > a").parent();
```

This gives you all td having anchor as an immediate child, from the table. My advice is to give id to the table than you should write:

```
var listOfTD = $("#tableid td > a").parent();
```